# Scroll to top of page on mat-pagination 'items per page' changes - angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want page to scroll to top if user changes `mat-paginator` 'items per page'. `scrollIntoView()` is not working. I have used `(page)="pageEvent = handlePage($event)` in code and can capture event change but I am not able to bind event with `scrollIntoView` event. I have also tried `window.scrollTo(0,0)` but it is also not working.

html

```
<table  **id="box"** mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="productCode">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-form-field class="p-1" style="text-align:center;">
            <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="productCodeFilter" placeholder="Product Code">
          </mat-form-field>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.productCode}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="batchNo">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-form-field class="p-1" style="text-align:center;">
            <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="batchNoFilter" placeholder="Batch Number">
          </mat-form-field>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.batchNo}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-form-field class="p-1" style="text-align:center;">
            <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="descriptionFilter" placeholder="Description">
          </mat-form-field>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="qty">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-form-field class="p-1" style="text-align:center;">
            <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="qtyFilter" placeholder="Quantity">
          </mat-form-field>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.qty}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="binId">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-form-field class="p-1" style="text-align:center;">
            <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="binIdFilter" placeholder="Bin Id">
          </mat-form-field>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.binId}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="zone">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-form-field class="p-1" style="text-align:center;">
            <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="zoneFilter" placeholder="Zone">
          </mat-form-field>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.zone}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="containerId">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-form-field class="p-1" style="text-align:center;">
            <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="containerIdFilter" placeholder="Container Id">
          </mat-form-field>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.containerId}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <mat-paginator *ngIf="dataSource!==undefined && dataSource.data.length!==0" class="float-right mt-2"
    [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons **(page)="pageEvent = handlePage($event)"**>
  </mat-paginator>
```

ts

```
handlePage(e: any) {
      //debugger;
      var element = document.getElementById("box");
      //alert('hi');
      element.scrollIntoView(true);
      //window.scrollTo(0,0)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy fix for this issue.Just add an id to the top div (incase you want to scroll to top) or where you want it to scroll after click.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" #focus>
     <mat-paginator (page)="scrollUp()"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

TS:

Here tableInput is used to get reference of the "Focus" element. Then we use [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to scroll to it's defined element.

```
@ViewChild('focus', { read: ElementRef }) tableInput: ElementRef;
scrollUp(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.tableInput.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: "end" }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish it worked in my case. Only change i made was in scrollUp(){} function i put block:start instead of block:end.

Comment: In my case I did not need to use the #focus and the viewChild. For some reason, on pageChanges using window.scrollTo(0,0) was enough, but when changing the items in page this was not working. However once I wrapped the window.scrollTo(0,0) in the setTimout it fixed my problem.